# How to Center ImageView in HorizontalScroll View Android

Tags: android, xml, imageview, horizontalscrollview

I have been trying to center a large wallpaper of 3000px x 1500px (roughly) to when loaded show the center of the image and then the user can scroll left or right to view the rest. I have looked at a few examples and it doesn't seem to help it always lands on the left of the image!

I just need another pair of eyes to point me in the right direction.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

   <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgFullscreen"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried calling scrollTo(imageWidth / 2, imageHeight / 2) on the HorizontalScrollView once the image has been added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you will need to set your linearlayout and imageView  width to "wrap_content" 
and then [measure](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#measure(int,%20int))
your scollView and get it's width , after that you need to get the [screen size](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29) [scrollTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo(int,%20int))  and then scroll to the middle

```
   middle Offset = (scrollView width - screen width ) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all the layout inside the scroll view should be

```
 android:orientation="horizontal"
```

and wrap the content for both widht and height

Finally what you want is to start the activity with the scroll view at the center. 
You can programmatically do that with something like

```
int centerX = scrollView.getChildAt(0).getWidth()/2;
int centerY = scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight()/2;
scrollView.scrollTo(centerX, centerY);
```

for instance in the onCreateView of your Activity

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working.. if it do the scroll to on the image view it shifts the image within the scroll. But i cant get the scroll view to shift.